# Is there some kind of #define in Android that I can use to simplify a statement?

Tags: java, android

Consider the java android statement:

```
Toast.makeText (this, "some message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
```

I would like to write something like this:

```
myToast ("some message here");
```

and then, it should be converted/translated/replaced by the the full version of statement.

I would like to know if Android Studio IDE (mine is 3.4.1) has some kind of helper since there is no pre-processor as in C, and so #define is not an option.

Comment: "it should be converted/translated/replaced by the the full version of statement" What do you think that would allow you to do that you can't otherwise do with a regular method?

Answer (score 4):

Just define a method:

```
static void myToast(Context ctx, String message) {
  Toast.makeText (ctx, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I already did. But I was wondering if there is something in Android Studio IDE, so I don't need to pollute my code with that silly thing...

Comment: `this` can't be referenced from a static context. You'd have to pass in a `Context` to `myToast()` or define this as an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is tagged with Java, but since you're talking Android I figure I'll give you a Kotlin solution as well.

Define an extension method on `Context`:

```
fun Context.myToast(str: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Now you can use this in any `Activity` (or any other `Context`) without having to define it everywhere.